# Why does a PSpice simulation result in a diode voltage drop of value 0.732V?

Tags: diodes, pspice

I simulated a resistor-diode circuit while inserting the required parameters to compute the necessary voltages and currents across the elements of the circuit

From a theoretical perspective, a real silicon diode when conducting drops a constant voltage of 0.7 V. However in my simulation results that constant voltage was 0.732 V

I know that by convention we choose 0.7 V to make mathematical modeling look "cleaner" but it seems that in simulation that value is always 0.732 V which leads me to wonder why and how it may be derived theoretically to this value.

Comment: *but it seems that in simulation that value is always 0.732 V* Try to set a different temperature and simulate again, is it still 0.732 V? Change the current, is it still 0.732 V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one true value. A theoretical value will not be 0.7V as it is a just rule of thumb. The actual voltage depends on current through the diode and the temperature of the diode. And manufacturing tolerances. So a theoretical voltage value for a certain kind of diode at certain temperature could be approximated to have some value like 0.732V at the current of interest.

It also depends on how good simulation model is used - it is possible that somebody looked at a datasheet of a real component where it said that at some temperature and at certain test current the voltage typically is a some known value and then that known value is used in the simulation model. It might be a simple simulation model that only works at DC, or a very complex model to work properly at some high frequencies.

So in your circuit, after the calculations are done using whatever model the diode happens to have, it just ends up being 0.732V in your circuit.